# Items being added to a list item multiple times. How do I fix this?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a listview with each list item is different and their layouts are created by code. The initial layouts look fine, but when i scroll out and in, all the layout items added programatically are added again, resulting duplicate items. How can I solve that problem?

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        MyHolder holder;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.empty_item, null);
            holder = new MyHolder(v);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MyHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
        textView.setText(items.get(position).getItems().get(i).getText());
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.linearLayout.addView(textView);
        return v;
        }

   class MyHolder{
        public TextView tvTitle;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public CardView cardView;
        public MyHolder(View base){

            tvTitle = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            cardView = (CardView)base.findViewById(R.id.card_view2);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout)base.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutCard);



        }
    }
```

Comment: why adding textview run-time please go through https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

Comment: I need dynamic layouts in my app. For example if server says we need 3 buttons and a textview, I create that run-time.

Comment: in this case your item will added when list state changes like scroll and notify then it will randomly add views , you can add holder.linearLayout.removeallview(); before adding view

Comment: This could also work, but drschultz provided me a better solution, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not even sure how this code is running, because you have no return statement in your `getView()` method. But you need to return the `convertView` in `getView()` so that the `ListView` can reuse those when it needs to. Otherwise, it'll just keep asking for new views every time it needs them. So you would just put `return v;` at the end of `getView()`.

Additionally, you are creating and adding new TextViews to your `MyHolder` objects outside of the `if (v == null)` block. Normally you would instantiate new views like this if the `convertView` is null. If it isn't, you just pass it through to the ListView or make updates to it before passing it back. So what's happening is, the `convertView` is available (not null), but instead of using it, you're adding a brand new `TextView` instead, which is why you are getting duplicates.

Comment: My bad, i cropped unnecesary parts and forgot to add return statement. There is a return v; at the end.

Comment: See my edits above. You only want to create new views when `convertView` is null. So the issue is likely the fact that you are creating and adding TextViews even when there is a `convertView` available. You only want to instantiate new views when `convertView` is null.

Comment: I moved the textview stuff in if statment and it worked. Thanks for clear and accurate anwser.